# Multiple Radio group in a single Activity

Tags: java, android, button, radio-button, onclicklistener

I'm Developing an android app in which the Questionnaire activity contains radio buttons for every question.And I've designed the activity in Linear layout.So now i wanted to check whether the user as answered all Questions.The problem I'm facing is in the public void OnClick(View v)help me in modifying the java code.
[image: Here is the view of my Activity]

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/Mquestion1"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_1_rb1" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_1_rb2" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_1_rb3" />
</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_2_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/Mquestion2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_2_rb1" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_2_rb2" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_2_rb3" />
</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_3_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/Mquestion3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_3_rb1" />

 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_3_rb2" />

 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MQ1_3_rb3" />
 </RadioGroup>
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="OnClickListener"
        android:text="@string/MQ1_next" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code

```
  public class ManagerQuestionnaire1 extends Activity
 {

Button next;
RadioGroup rg1;
RadioGroup rg2;
RadioGroup rg3;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager_questionnaire1);
    final RadioGroup    rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Mquestion1);
     final RadioGroup   rg2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Mquestion2);
     final RadioGroup   rg3=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Mquestion3);
    Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void OnClick(View v) \\The error I'm getting here is REMOVE method'OnClick'
                {

                    if((rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton1 || rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton2 || rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton3)||(rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton4 || rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton5 || rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton6)||(rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton7 || rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton8 || rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=R.id.radioButton9))
                    {
                         AlertDialog alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(ManagerQuestionnaire1.this).create();
                         alert.setTitle("Exception:Complete the Questions");
                         alert.setMessage("Please ensure all Questions are answered");
                    }
                    else    
                    {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(ManagerQuestionnaire1.this, ManagerQuestionnaire2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


    });
 }
```

Comment: go to this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: I checked these sites before itself they all show with two radio buttons.Mine is with multiple radio buttons and I wanted to radiogroup them with changing the alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always recommended to user radiobuttons inside a radioGroup

like this :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/question2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Now whenever you want to see which answer is selected corrosponding to which radio group you can do something like this :

```
RadioGroup question1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question1);
        String answer1 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(question1.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Congrates ! you got the answer here

Comment: #Sarkar your xml code was very helpful. Can you help me with the java code ?

Comment: #Steve what kind of help you are seeking regarding java code

Comment: Use a button . 
Handle its onClick

on its onClick, do execute this code for every question :

 String answer1 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(question1.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

Add this answer1 to an array of answers 


after the loop you will get all answer filled by user ...
compare them with right answer array..
you got the score.. 
Have fun and mark it as answer if you found this helpful

Comment: Yeah It sounds like I understood but i don't how far I'm gonna implement it in the code. will try my best and update you.Anyhow thanks for your time and concern Sarkar..

Comment: Sarkar, Check my Post I've modified my java code.Can you please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had a similar problem and was having a hard time getting away from clickListeners.

Answer (score 0):

change your xml file here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_1_view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_1_rb1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_1_rb2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_1_rb3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_2_view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_2_rb1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_2_rb2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_2_rb3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_3_view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_3_rb1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_3_rb2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MQ1_3_rb3" />
</RadioGroup>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MQ1_next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your java class define id for radiogroups.

Comment: but is that enough if I just use one radiogroup? Like you used in the above xml.

Comment: ya by using this your layout willnot change